# Software to rename files with Japanese or Korean character/letter filenames to their Romanized (Roman/Latin letters) equivalents

Tags: windows, software-rec, language, translation

Is there a program (for Windows) that will rename files with Japanese or Korean characters/letters in their filenames to their Romanized (Roman/Latin letters) equivalents (preferably Hepburn Romanization for Japanese and Revised Romanization for Korean).

Comment: Link to related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221003/a-program-command-to-help-translate-multiple-file-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=downloads&product=renamer) *v6.5* comes with transliteration maps for Japanese language. Included maps adhere to [Hepburn-shiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization) and [Kunrei-shiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunrei-shiki_romanization) romanization systems.

[image: Japanese transliteration map in ReNamer]

Answer (score 2):

Try the latest portable beta of [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=downloads&product=renamer) (an extremely powerful bulk renamer with in-built scripting support), then take a look at its [Transliteration](http://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Rules:Translit) feature. The forum is pretty helpful as well and the developer is quite responsive to suggestions/requests, so if your language isn't supported out of the box maybe someone has shared their translit file in the forum or is willing to help.

Comment: I was thinking "great!" but then I saw it does not support either Japanese or Korean (and making a transliteration map for Japanese would take AGES!).

Comment: Well *someone* has to do it, right? :) Like I said, ask on the forum, maybe the hard work's already been done for you.