# How to bulk translate file names and rename them

Tags: windows, linux, filenames, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to rename files with Japanese or Korean character/letter filenames to their Romanized (Roman/Latin letters) equivalents](https://superuser.com/questions/122274/software-to-rename-files-with-japanese-or-korean-character-letter-filenames-to-t)

I have some files with Chinese names. I want to translate them into English or code so that I can easily handle the files on my PHP website.

How could I do that? I can either use Windows or Linux.

Comment: The other question has no answers.  It's useless to flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: No actually it is not useless. Two questions that don't get answered dilute the Question/Answer pool on the site.

Comment: Ideally the best way for the OP to handle this is to do a few things. If the OP has more pertinent and relevant information they should edit the original question to add the information which will essentially bump it. In this case it is not an option due to the OP's re. Next, the OP (or a generous interested 3rd party) could offer a bounty on the original question. Lastly the OP (or again anyone interested) could promote the question on various social sites on their own. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5485/is-bumping-a-question-ok

Comment: Link to related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221003/a-program-command-to-help-translate-multiple-file-names